# How to declare var as global which stores value of controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two radio buttons in CriminalityInformationFormViewDisposal and I'm finding this controls dynamically as follows

```
var siaHasConvictions = 
((RadioButtonList)CriminalityInformationFormViewDisposal.FindControl(ContactEntity.SIA_HASCOVICTIONS));
var siaHasOffencesAwatingTrial = 
((RadioButtonList)CriminalityInformationFormViewTrial.FindControl(ContactEntity.SIA_HASOFFENCEAWAITINGTRIAL));
```

now on one page whenever I need to fetch the value of radio buttons i.e. whether it is selected or not every time I need to define var to find control first and then I check for its value...now it increases code line ..is there any way so I can make this findcontrol part global for that one page and then I access its value like we do for normal control ,please help me out for this,as I tried it to declare before page load,,,but gives error for gridcontrol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no easy way in my opinion, but this might help you not repeat the code over and over again:

```
private RadioButtonList SiaHasConvictions
{
    get
    {
        return (RadioButtonList)CriminalityInformationFormViewDisposal.FindControl(ContactEntity.SIA_HASCOVICTIONS);
    }
}
```

With this property, you can just use `this.SiaHasConvictions` in your code. You could optimize this by saving the reference once in a variable:

```
private RadioButtonList _siaHasConvictions;
private RadioButtonList SiaHasConvictions
{
    get
    {
        if (this._siaHasConvictions == null)
        {
            this._siaHasConvictions = (RadioButtonList)CriminalityInformationFormViewDisposal.FindControl(ContactEntity.SIA_HASCOVICTIONS);
        }

        return this._siaHasConvictions;
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the idea of using property, but using the second approach may not be a good idea. His `FindControl` method finds control dynamically and may not always return the same control. By doing the second approach, once `_siaHasConvictions` is set, it won't change.

Comment: Depends whether it is static per page load. If so, you can use it. Otherwise you can't. Depends on the code from OP, which is missing. Thanks for the heads up though.

Comment: @shweta: Need more help?

Answer (score 0):

Using the second piece of @Patrick Hofman's code is **NOT** guaranteed a correct behavior. If the `FindControl` method may return different values each time you call it, this implementation will go wrong since `_siaHasConvictions` won't get changed anymore once set.

---

However, I was inspired from @Patrick Hofman's idea of using property, you could use `??` operator in your Property to make things even easier:

```
private RadioButtonList _siaHasConvictions;
private RadioButtonList SiaHasConvictions
{
    get { return this._siaHasConvictions ?? (this._siaHasConvictions = (RadioButtonList)CriminalityInformationFormViewDisposal.FindControl(ContactEntity.SIA_HASCOVICTIONS)); }
}
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) is the explanation and some examples of using `??` operator, and in short:

> The `??` operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand.

Comment: you never actually set the _siaHasConvitions though

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig you are right I forgot to set it. Thanks for pointing it out.